# Codeigniter 4 403 error on shared host in Namecheap

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, subdomain, codeigniter-4

I have this system that is working pretty well on localhost and on another domain (domain a). I have done a few modifications and installed the system in a subdomain in domain B (new.domain.com).
However, one form is giving me a 403 error when I hit `Submit`. All the other functions are working fine, even other forms.
I have checked all the permissions on the system but all seems ok.

My .htaccess is also ok.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Below is my controller:

```
public function storeCourse() {
    $data['cats'] = $this->$cats;
    helper(['form', 'url']);


    $courseModel = new CourseModel();

    $validated = $this->validate([
        'file' => [
            'uploaded[image]',
            'mime_in[image,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png]',
            'max_size[image,4096]',
        ],
    ]);

    $random = "";
    if ($validated) {
        $random = $this->randomString();
        $avatar = $this->request->getFile('image');
        $fileName = $avatar->getName();
        $nameArray = explode('.', $fileName);
        $ext = $nameArray[1];
        $random = $random . "." . $ext;
        $fileP = $avatar->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads/');
        rename(WRITEPATH . "uploads/" . $fileName, WRITEPATH . "../public/images/courses/" . $random);

        $msg = 'File has been uploaded';
    } else {
        $random = "default.jpg";
    }

    $data = [

        'facultyID' => $this->request->getVar('category'),
        'courseName' => $this->request->getVar('coursename'),
        'introText' => $this->request->getVar('introtext', TRUE),
        'duration' => $this->request->getVar('duration'),
        'durationType' => $this->request->getVar('durationtype'),
        'targetAudience' => $this->request->getVar('targetgroup'),
        'methodology' => $this->request->getVar('methodology'),
        'courseObjectives' => $this->request->getVar('objectives'),
        'software' => $this->request->getVar('software'),
        'feeKshs' => $this->request->getVar('feekshs'),
        'feeUsd' => $this->request->getVar('feeusd'),
        'meta_desc' => $this->request->getVar('meta_desc'),
        'meta_keywords' => $this->request->getVar('meta_keywords'),
        'imgUrl' => $random,
        'createdBy' => 1,
    ];

    $courseID = $courseModel->insert($data);
    $data['success'] = $courseID;
    if ($courseID > 0) {
        $mod1 = $this->request->getVar('moduleone');
        $mod1items = $this->request->getVar('moduleoneitems');
        $mod2 = $this->request->getVar('moduletwo');
        $mod2items = $this->request->getVar('moduletwoitems');
        $mod3 = $this->request->getVar('modulethree');
        $mod3items = $this->request->getVar('modulethreeitems');
        $mod4 = $this->request->getVar('modulefour');
        $mod4items = $this->request->getVar('modulefouritems');


        if (strlen($mod1) > 0) {
            $data = [

                'courseID' => $courseID,
                'outlineItem' => $mod1,
                'outlineItems' => $mod1items,
                'createdBy' => 1,
            ];
            $courseOutlineModel = new CourseOutlineModel();
            $courseItemID = $courseOutlineModel->insert($data);

        }
        if (strlen($mod2) > 0) {
            $data = [

                'courseID' => $courseID,
                'outlineItem' => $mod2,
                'outlineItems' => $mod2items,
                'createdBy' => 1,
            ];
            $courseOutlineModel = new CourseOutlineModel();
            $courseItemID = $courseOutlineModel->insert($data);

        }
        if (strlen($mod3) > 0) {
            $data = [

                'courseID' => $courseID,
                'outlineItem' => $mod3,
                'outlineItems' => $mod3items,
                'createdBy' => 1,
            ];
            $courseOutlineModel = new CourseOutlineModel();
            $courseItemID = $courseOutlineModel->insert($data);

        }
        if (strlen($mod4) > 0) {
            $data = [

                'courseID' => $courseID,
                'outlineItem' => $mod4,
                'outlineItems' => $mod4items,
                'createdBy' => 1,
            ];
            $courseOutlineModel = new CourseOutlineModel();
            $courseItemID = $courseOutlineModel->insert($data);

        }

    }


    $data['saved'] = 1;
    $data['success'] = $courseID;

    $facultyModel = new FacultyModel();
    $data['cats'] = $facultyModel->orderBy('facultyName', 'ASC')->findAll();
    $data['addCourse'] = 1;

    echo view('templates/admin/admin-header', $data);
    echo view('addcourse', $data);
    echo view('templates/admin/admin-footer');
```

I have done everything I can but I haven't made headways.

Comment: Need more info such as the HTML page that is submitting to this, the url with the domain removed etc.  It's rough to figure out a 403 with nothing but a single page.  And of course you have  `ini_set("display_errors",TRUE); error_reporting(E_ALL);` turned on

Answer (score 0):

My hosting company was able to assist. The problem was that `ModSecurity rule` blocked the specific action in my account.

Adding this to your `.htaccess` will solve the problem.

```
 <IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

ModSecurity is a server-side web application firewall
that is designed to block attempts of possibly malicious injections of various snippets into your website scripts; however, in some cases these
blocks are false-positive.

My problem was brought about by pasting content from MsWord, whose hidden formatting scripts were detected as malicious scripts.

[Check this link for more info](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-disable-mod_security-in-apache-using-htaccess/)